# Export image from photoshop to blender

Tags: uv

I'm trying to shape an effect on photoshop and use it on blender.
I already did the most part, but I'm having problems on getting the spiral texture on the outside of the object.
What should I do to fix it?[image]

Comment: so you are making a texture in photoshop, and just want to use that in the object in blender?

Comment: Have you created a UV map for the object?